# FastApi - Swagger UI

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Установил FastAPI в соответствии с [документацией](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#installation). Однако FastApi - Swagger UI http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs отображается некорректно. В чем может быть проблема (браузер Firefox 87)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В консоли (layout.js:99:14): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, по каким-то причинам в браузере был закеширован кривой css. Попробуйте Ctrl+F5 - мне помогло.